# Is there a way to create a graph comparing hyper-parameters vs model accuracy with TRAINS python package?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, trains, clearml

I would like to run multiple experiments, then report model accuracy per experiment.

I'm training a toy MNIST example with pytorch (v1.1.0), but the goal is, once I can compare performance for the toy problem, to have it integrated with the actual code base.

As I understand the TRAINS python package, with the "two lines of code" all my hyper-parameters are already logged (Command line argparse in my case).

What do I need to do in order to report a final scalar and then be able to sort through all the different training experiments (w/ hyper-parameters) in order to find the best one.

What I'd like to get, is a graph/s where on the X-axis I have hyper-parameter values and on the Y-axis I have the validation accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to: https://pypi.org/project/trains/ (https://github.com/allegroai/trains), 
which I'm one of the maintainers.

You can manually create a plot with a single point X-axis for the hyper-parameter value, and Y-Axis for the accuracy.

```
number_layers = 10
accuracy = 0.95
Task.current_task().get_logger().report_scatter2d(
    "performance", "accuracy", iteration=0, 
    mode='markers', scatter=[(number_layers, accuracy)])
```

Assuming your hyper-parameter is "number_layers" with current value 10, and the accuracy for the trained model is 0.95.

Then when you compare the experiments you get something like that:

[image: compare scatter plots]

Comment: You could also have a histogram instead of 2D scatter plot:

Task.current_task().get_logger().report_vector(
    "performance", "accuracy", iteration=0, labels=['accuracy'],
    values=[accuracy], xlabels=['number_layers %d' % number_layers])

Comment: great! I like the histogram even better
Thanks

Comment: @Martin.B it looks like you have some kind of affiliation with the TRAINS project. There is nothing wrong about it. However, [users are expected to disclose their affiliations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) in these cases. Would you mind to add a disclaimer disclosing it?

Comment: @Berriel my apologies, I now made sure my affiliation is noticable in my profile.
I will also make sure it is clear on my next replies

Comment: @Martin.B I think you didn't read the link I posted. You must disclose the affiliation on your answers. Doing it on your profile is your choice. Can you update this answer with a disclaimer?

Comment: @Berriel, sure I edited the original answer to include my affiliation, let me know if it is clear enough.