# trains with grid search

Tags: python, trains, clearml

I would like to test [trains](https://github.com/allegroai/trains) usage during grid search and it not clear how to do so.

```
from trains import Task 
Task.init(project_name="project name", task_name='name')
```

creates an experiment in the demo server and logs all but you can't call init twice no matter the 'task_name' and

```
from trains import Task 
Task.create(project_name="project name", task_name='name')
```

can be called with different 'task_name' but thus not log any data into the server and creates only 'Draft'.

here is a sample code:

```
 epochs=[160,300]
 for epoch in epochs:
    model = define_model_run(epoch)
    model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    score = model.score(...)
```

my final try was:

```
 epochs=[160,300]
 task=Task.init(project_name="demo", task_name='search')
 for epoch in epochs:
    task.create(project_name="demo", task_name=f'search_{epoch}')
    model = define_model_run(epoch)
    model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    score = model.score(...)
```

which logs all information under the experiments tab and none under the 'Draft'.
I tried the last two hour the read the few documentations provided and reading the source code, but no luck.

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaimer: I'm a member of TRAINS team

Yes, that's exactly the answer.
The idea is that you always have one main Task, in order to create a new one you need to close the running Task, and re-initialize with a new name.
Kudos on solving it so quickly :)

BTW: You can see examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56744397/11682840)/[and here](https://github.com/allegroai/trains/blob/master/docs/faq.md#can-i-create-a-graph-comparing-hyper-parameters-vs-model-accuracy-), showing how to send accuracy logs so it is easier to compare the experiments, especially when running hyper-parameter search.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by looking on closed bugs in their GitHub repository: [link](https://github.com/allegroai/trains/issues/18#issuecomment-507683620)

```
 epochs=[160,300]
 for epoch in epochs:
    task=Task.init(project_name="demo", task_name=f'search_{epoch}')
    model = define_model_run(epoch)
    model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    score = model.score(...)
    task.close()
```

then each task is a different experiment in project "demo".